# How do I list long running shell script?

Tags: unix

Currently we are running lot of UNIX shell scripts in HP-UX. We want to track which scripts are running long time (more than 1 day), how can we track that?

Furthermore I want to list long running UNIX Job for more than certain hours example 10 hrs, how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of HP-UX you're running, but if you do a `ps -ef`, one of the columns in the output will be *stime* (or process starting time).  Once the elapsed time of the process exceeds 24 hours, the starting time (stime) will be printed as a starting date instead (like "Mar23").  You could sort the output of `ps` using this starting date.

If you simply wanted to list the processes which have been running 24 hours or longer (as you stipulated in your question), just omit the lines where stime is still a time (like `23:11`).  If stime is column number 5 in your output, then you could omit any line with a colon in that field using `ps -ef | awk '$5 !~ /:/'`